# RESOLVE - Problem when using assets from database in symfony

Tags: sql, symfony, video, assets

I have a little problem when I use an asset.

[error capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9gh7.png)

In my database I have the link of videos which are stocked in my server and for example one of them is : **Commande/test/a/2362022a.mp4**, the right path of the file is **myProject/public/Commande/test/a/2362022a.mp4**
So I try to do this :

```
<video controls>
    <source src="{{ asset(commande.lienVideo)}}" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

But I have this error :

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Asset manifest file "/var/www/html/app_brobro/public/build/manifest.json" does not exist. Did you forget to build the assets with npm or yarn?").
```

I also try this, but I have got the same error :

```
<video controls>
    <source src="{{ asset('/' ~ commande.lienVideo)}}" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

I hope someone will have a solution to this ^^

Thanks by advance and have a nice day !

Comment: Did you build the project with  `npm run build` ou `yarn dev` ? I think the problem comes from here before the rest.

Comment: I build it with composer like asked by symfony, but no I never use npm or yarn

Comment: Well, the error does ask if you forgot to build the assets with `npm` or `yarn`. So if I had got an error like that, I would first look to see if there was a `package-lock.json` file where ever the `package.json` file is, or even a `yarn.lock` file. Also followed by looking for the `scripts` section in the `package.json` file. If you have `yarn.lock`, try the `yarn` commands. If you have the `package-lock.json`, try the `npm` commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to our exchanges in comments here is your solution:

**As the official Symfony documentation specifies** [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/simple-example.html#configuring-encore-webpack), you have to build your Webpack with `yarn dev` by default or `npm run build` if you prefer npm to manage your front dependencies.

So just run one of them and that's it !

Comment: Hi, I try both of them, and no one works.
For yarn  : ERROR: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'dev'
For npm run build : 
sh: 1: encore: not found
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! syscall spawn
npm ERR! file sh
npm ERR! errno ENOENT
npm ERR! @ build: `encore production --progress`
npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/test/.npm/_logs/2022-06-27T17_30_29_642Z-debug.log

Comment: Ok, please can you add a screenshot of your project's tree structure ?

Comment: Hi, I have done over researchs and I finally found the problem, I have a "webpack" install in my project, and when I remove it, I could use my assets :) SO my problem is resolve !

Comment: Nice job @EileenBalaguer !